# Pass values to $('form').submit(function ()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am absolute begginner for the programming. Here I want to pass a argument to `$('form').submit(function () {`. Just I want to pass the `email` value to `.submit() function`, that has been created like this,

Here is the HTML code,

```
<div id="friends">   
<?php

$query=$pdo->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM users as u
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM appointment as a
                  WHERE u.user_id = a.user_id AND 
                  a.p_id= '".$_SESSION['p_id']."')");

$row=$query->execute();
$rs=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

foreach ($rs as $message){  
    $filename=  $message->image;
    $filepath="../../adminpanel/profile/blog/"; 
?> 
<div class="friend">  
<?php   
    printf(
        '<img class="inline-block" src="data:image/png;base64, %s" alt="user" />',
             base64_encode(file_get_contents($filepath.$filename ) )
    );  
?>
       <p>
            <strong> <?php        echo $message->username   ?></strong> <br>
            <span id="email"><?php  echo $message->email   ?></span>
       </p>
     <div class="status available"></div>
  </div>
<?php   } ?>
```

Here is the HTML for `submit` button

```
<form class="" id="msgform" action="chat.php" method="post">        
    <div id="sendmessage">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Send message..."  class="textarea" name="message"/>
        <button id="send" class="textarea" ></button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Below is the `javascript` code, that how to set `email` to `html` to appear.

```
 $(".friend").each(function(x){     
    $(this).click(function(){
                                                                
    var name = $(this).find("p strong").html();
    var email = $(this).find("p span").html();
                        
    LoadChat(email);
                                                    
    $("#profile p").html(name);
    $("#profile span").html(email);              
                         
     });    
    });
```

I have passed this `email` variable to `submit` function, but always takes the `email` of last user. Here is the `.submit` function to sent data to `server`.

```
$('form').submit(function() {
  const email = <?= json_encode($message->email) ?>
  var message = $('.textarea').val();

  if ($(".textarea").val()) {

    $.post("handlers/messages.php", {
      action: "sendMessage",
      message: message,
      email: email
    }, function(response) {
      if (response == 1) {
        LoadChat();
        document.getElementById('msgform').reset();
      }
    });
  } else {
    myFunction();
  }
  return false;
})
```

Just I want to pass the particular `email` value to `submit` function. Please help me may highly appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: <?= json_encode($message->email) ?> this is server side, will always show the email saved. you need a new email, please select the value by proper selector, either get it by id or class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('form').submit(function() {
var email = $('#email').val();
var message = $('.textarea').val();

if ($(".textarea").val()) {

$.post("handlers/messages.php", {
  action: "sendMessage",
  message: message,
  email: email
}, function(response) {
  if (response == 1) {
    LoadChat();
    document.getElementById('msgform').reset();
  }
});
} else {
  myFunction();
}
return false;
})
```

You were getting the email which was printed by php (server side). You need to send what is on client or browser side.

```
var email = $('#email').val();
```

This will solve your issue